# Sitecore Path Analyzer: System.InvalidOperationException: This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable

Tags: c#, sitecore, upgrade

Has anyone encountered the issue below while upgrading the **Path Analyzer** from v.8.0 to v.8.1?

> There was an error while upgrading maps:
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: This SqlTransaction has completed;
>   it is no longer usable. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.ZombieCheck() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Rollback() at
>   Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Data.Storage.TreeDefinitionQueries.DeleteDefinitions()
>   at
>   Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Data.TreeDefinitionService.DeleteAllDefinitions()
>   at
>   Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Data.MapItemDeploymentManager.RedeployAll(Boolean
>   bubbleWorkflowExceptions) at
>   Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Client.Sitecore.Admin.PathAnalyzer.btnUpgrade_OnClick(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)'

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**URL**: http://PROJECT/sitecore/admin/pathanalyzer.aspx

Upon looking in the log file, I noticed similar log trace - with this [post](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/5/t/3512) - in the sitecore community forum.

I doubled-check and applied the given solution from [Sitecore 8.1 Upgrade Guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/Sitecore_81/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_81_Initial_Release.aspx), but it didn't work out for me. So it seems like I'm missing a very important step out there or probably a config related issue. :)

Pasting the log trace here:

> 3732 10:34:04 ERROR [Path Analyzer]
>   TreeMerger.MergeTreesForDefinition() failed: DefinitionId =
>   8690c11c-621b-4515-ad63-267cd82a4ff3, startDate = 11/5/2015 12:00:00
>   AM, endDate = 18/5/2015 12:00:00 AM Exception:
>   System.InvalidCastException Message: Unable to cast object of type
>   'Sitecore.SequenceAnalyzer.SerializableNode' to type
>   'Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Data.Models.ExperienceNode'. Source:
>   Sitecore.SequenceAnalyzer    at proto_3(Object , ProtoReader )    at
>   ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key,
>   ProtoReader reader, Type type)    at proto_6(Object , ProtoReader )
>   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeserializeCore(ProtoReader reader, Type
>   type, Object value, Boolean noAutoCreate)    at
>   ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source, Object value, Type
>   type, SerializationContext context)    at
>   Sitecore.SequenceAnalyzer.SerializableTree`2.Deserialize(Byte[] blob) 
>   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Construction.TreeFactory.ParseTree(Byte[]
>   blob)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Construction.TreeMerger.MergeTrees(IEnumerable`1
>   trees)    at
>   Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Construction.TreeMerger.GetMergedTreeForDefinition(ITreeStorage
>   storage, TreeDefinition definition, DateTime startDate, DateTime
>   endDate, Boolean& mergeComplete)    at
>   Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Construction.TreeMerger.MergeTreesForDefinition(ITreeStorage
>   storage, TreeDefinition definition, DateTime startDate, DateTime
>   endDate)

After applying the support patch provided by Sitecore Climber.

[image]

Although, I've tried several adjustment on SSMS side and on the website configurations

Appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Hi Roman, Yes. the Historic Map Rebuild was completed successfully without any issue. This is after the "In the upgrade section click the upgrade button" step in the SC upgrade guide. I also tried rebuilding the reporting database using the /sitecore/admin/rebuildreportdb.aspx it it was also completed without any issue, but still getting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please add  dll file into bin folder and the config file into the /App_Config/Include/Z.SwitchMasterToWeb folder and run upgrade again.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g55mbdfw1slc6ah/Sitecore.Support.452199.dll?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtqx0xaiq19ieno/Sitecore.Support.452199.config?dl=0

Comment: increase the value of  <setting name="DefaultSQLTimeout" value="03:00:00" />

Comment: Hmm. Let me try that. I did changed it to 01:00:00 (equivalent to 1hr), and it's still throwing the timeout issue (see updated question).

Comment: can you try to restart your sql and w3p process and try again

Comment: I did that several times already :) Let me try the DefaultSQLTimeout adjustment.

Comment: you can put 00:00:00 for timeout, that's mean infinity. But don't forget to change it back after you run the upgrade

Comment: Tried all the suggestions, but still encounter the problem. :( I will have sometime tonight to dissect the issue further.